# Eclipse RCP doesn't unpack jar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse has an option on features to unpack the jar file.  This is not working for me.

When I check the box **Unpack the plug-in archive after installation**, the PDE tooling removes the *unpack* attribute completely from that jar. I have tried this configuration as well as changing it to *unpack="true"*.  Neither result in the jar being unpacked during build, installation or after running the executable.

Any suggestions on how to get the jar automatically unpacked?

Thanks for taking time to read my question!

Excerpt of feature.xml to unpack *com.easa.motordb.services.remote*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="com.easa.motordb.feature"
      label="Feature"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier"
      provider-name="EASA">

...

   <plugin
         id="com.easa.motordb.client.eclipse"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="com.easa.motordb.services.remote"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"/>

</feature>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I checked the box **Unpack the plug-in archive after installation** in my feature.xml that includes plugin_1 and plugin_2, but after building my project the jar of plugin_2 still appears and was not unpacked.

I had a plugin_1 already where this unpacking works and by looking for differences between these two plugins I found something:

The MANIFEST.MF file from my working plugin_1 had an additional line which was missing in my other not working plugin_2:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

I just added this line to the MANIFEST.MF file of plugin_2 and the unpacking works as expected.

Comment: This works only if the bundle and feature in question are under your control. I have such a situation with a third-party feature that is include in a product build using Tycho. In feature.xml, `unpack` is set to `true`, but in the (fragment) bundle's MANIFEST.MF, `Eclipse-BundleShape` is unset. Not sure what to do yet.